# mysql trigger - Compare Values Different Table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I am learning SQL, I am using mysql workbench and I have a problem related with trigger.

I have two tables, one to them called DireccionEntrega with attributes: idDir, idT, idPed, Road, Pais, Region. The other called Cobertura with attributes: idCob, idProv, Pais, Region.

I want to create a trigger for table DireccionEntrega so that when I insert a values in it, the values of Country and Region of table DireccionEntrega, they must be in the table Cobertura. If not, an error message is displayed.

I show you how I created the trigger:

```
create trigger Comprobacion before insert on DireccionEntrega 
for each row
begin

    if not exists(select Cobertura.idProv, Cobertura.Pais, Cobertura.Region from Cobertura, Proveedor, LineasPedido where
                    Cobertura.idProv = Proveedor.idProv and Proveedor.idProv = LineasPedido.idProv)
        then
        signal sqlstate '45000'
                set message_text = 'Error insert...';
    end if;
end;
```

I do not what is happening but its not working how I expect.

The expectations of the trigger is following like this:

```
insert into DireccionEntrega(Pais, Region) values ('Spain','West')
```

it's okey because I have that information in Cobertura.

```
insert into DireccionEntrega(Pais, Region) values ('Portugal','South')
```

it's wrong because I don't have that information in Cobertura.

If you need something to solve what I want, please let me know and answer whatever you want.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) example of the issue here? ... also, it's time to ditch the 1992 style of comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause and use `JOIN`s as expected, and quit using `WHERE`-clause joins.

Comment: In a before insert trigger I would expect to see reference to NEW. values (ie the values to be inserted) see manual for more details. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html . Also triggers hare hard to debug and I usually create a helper debug_table and write to that

Comment: I don't know how to create dbfiddle but I get that: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/RlyFSipo). I wish you want that..

Comment: Yeah, @P.Salmon, but I do not know how to write it because the new values are NEW.Pais and NEW.Region and that's pairing I have to compare over the whole table called Cobertura... Do you know something about it? How you create that helper debug_table as well?

Comment: insert into DireccionEntrega(Pais, Region) values ('España','Este'); fails becauase id1 does not have a default value and you didn't provide one. Please fix.

Comment: I provide more values in it but i have another problem. It's that: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/5d8g3wxY) @P.Salmon

Comment: Error is self explanatory. dbfiddle hint to debug use the + to create more code windows split the code into smaller self contained blocks and place in separate code windows.

Comment: Okey, I separate in different code windows. If I put 'If exists', the trigger don't let me insert into table DireccionEntrega. Otherwise, if I put 'if not exists', directly the trigger entered into the table DireccionEntrega. Here the code link [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/xBrdsxqu) @P.Salmon

Comment: @Paul T. Here the dbfidle example: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/xBrdsxqu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for the dbfiddle!

So, to NOT find a matching pair of Country and Region in Cobertura, before insert into table DireccionEntrega, the trigger handling changes to:

```
 if not exists(
      select Cobertura.Pais, Cobertura.Region 
        from Cobertura
          join Proveedor ON Cobertura.idProv = Proveedor.idProv
          join LineasPedido ON Proveedor.idProv = LineasPedido.idProv
        where Cobertura.Pais = NEW.Pais and Cobertura.Region = NEW.Region
    ) then
    set @message = CONCAT(
       'Error insert... did not find a matching pair for: ', 
        NEW.Pais, ' and ', NEW.Region, ' in Cobertura.'
    );
    signal sqlstate '45000'
            set message_text = @message;
 end if;
```

So with the two fiddle insert query examples:

```
insert into DireccionEntrega(idT, idPed, N, Calle, Poblacion, Ciudad, Telefono, email, Pais, Region) 
values (1,1,13,'Alba','malaga','malaga', 654544434,'shop1@gmail.com','España','Este');

insert into DireccionEntrega(idT, idPed, N, Calle, Poblacion, Ciudad, Telefono, email, Pais, Region) 
values (1,2,11,'CAdd','dos hermanas','sevilla', 654544434,'shop1@gmail.com','Portugal','Oeste');
```

Because neither `España and Este` and `Portugal and Oeste` are not found in `Cobertura`, both give the error:

```
Error insert... did not find a matching pair for: España and Este in Cobertura.
Error insert... did not find a matching pair for: Portugal and Oeste in Cobertura.
```

So those 2 records do NOT get inserted.

Here's the updated [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/d-pDlbEs) with the trigger change applied.